# compilation terminated: How to install FiSHLiM on Ubuntu and Debian

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling, irc, hexchat

How do I [install](https://fishlim.kodafritt.se/ubuntu_install.html) `fishlim`?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt install build-essential libglib2.0-dev libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libglib2.0-doc libssl-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential libglib2.0-dev libssl-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,962 kB/2,967 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev amd64 2.58.1-2 [1,394 kB]
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1 [1,568 kB]
Fetched 2,962 kB in 6s (536 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
(Reading database ... 189033 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglib2.0-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-dev_2.58.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.58.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssl-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-dev_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.58.1-2) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.58.1-2) ...
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ git clone git://git.fishlim.kodafritt.se/fishlim.git
Cloning into 'fishlim'...
remote: Counting objects: 234, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (233/233), done.
remote: Total 234 (delta 158), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (234/234), 48.65 KiB | 119.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (158/158), done.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cd fishlim/
thufir@dur:~/fishlim$ 
thufir@dur:~/fishlim$ make
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 libcrypto` -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED=1 -fPIC  -c irc.c -o irc.o
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 libcrypto` -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED=1 -fPIC  -c fish.c -o fish.o
fish.c: In function ‘fish_encrypt_cbc’:
fish.c:140:5: warning: ‘RAND_pseudo_bytes’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     RAND_pseudo_bytes(iv, 8);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/blowfish.h:13,
                 from fish.c:27:
/usr/include/openssl/rand.h:44:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(int RAND_pseudo_bytes(unsigned char *buf, int num))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 libcrypto` -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED=1 -fPIC  -c keystore.c -o keystore.o
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 libcrypto` -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED=1 -fPIC  -c misc.c -o misc.o
misc.c: In function ‘import_glib_string’:
misc.c:43:5: warning: ‘g_mem_is_system_malloc’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     if (g_mem_is_system_malloc()) return gstr;
     ^~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glist.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:50,
                 from misc.c:25:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmem.h:378:10: note: declared here
 gboolean g_mem_is_system_malloc (void);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 libcrypto` -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED=1 -fPIC  -c plugin_xchat.c -o plugin_xchat.o
plugin_xchat.c:33:14: fatal error: hexchat-plugin.h: No such file or directory
     #include <hexchat-plugin.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:27: plugin_xchat.o] Error 1
thufir@dur:~/fishlim$ 
thufir@dur:~/fishlim$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~/fishlim$
```

The encryption [package](https://git.fishlim.kodafritt.se/fishlim/) was last updated 2015.

Comment: Keep in mind that BLOWFISH on its own is not sane to use anymore for two reasons: (1) It's weak encryption.  (2) It's deprecated for the most part.  If you *must* use Blowfish you're probably doing something wrong.  As for your compilation errors with Hexchat you probably need the Hexchat dev headers/source code or you aren't linking them right.

Comment: looks like you need to install hexchat or edit your makefile to not include said plugin

Comment: I have hexchat installed already before I ran make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it seems that you should install the package containing `hexchat-plugin.h` file.
  According to the search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=hexchat-plugin.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=cosmic&arch=any) it is named `hexchat-dev`.
So you need to install it:

```
sudo apt install hexchat-dev
```